# Issue with dynamically creating jagged array in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, debugging

I am trying to store each iteration of an array as it is being sorted through. For some reason the jagged array I return just becomes an array of the final sorted array. My code is below I cannot figure out why any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
namespace SortingUI.Utils
{
    public class Sorting
    {
        public static int[][] SortInt(int[] originalArray)
        {
            int length = originalArray.Length;
            int tempVal, smallest;
            int[][] iterations = new int[length-1][];

            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            {
                smallest = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
                {
                    if (originalArray[j] < originalArray[smallest])
                    {
                        smallest = j;
                    }
                }
                tempVal = originalArray[smallest];
                originalArray[smallest] = originalArray[i];
                originalArray[i] = tempVal;
                iterations[i] = originalArray;
            }

            return iterations;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"For some reason the jagged array I return just becomes an array of the final sorted array."* what do you specifically mean by this, and what is it you are actually trying do

Comment: @MichaelRandall I want to store an array of arrays where each iteration through the sorting I save what the array I am sorting is. However, the array called iterations which I return ends up just being an array of arrays with each element being the finally sorted array.

Comment: Ahh i see so you want snap shots of the sorting process?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yeah exactly. And looking at what I have I dont understand why but if u pass the function [1, 10, 4, 3] it will just return an array of arrays with each element as [1, 3, 4, 10].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your problem, the reason you are getting the same values (and not a snapshot) is because you are storing a reference to the array, and not a copy of the values themselves.

Arrays are *reference types*, so when you assign them to another variable you are only copying *reference* and not the contents. If you change the contents, all the references will reflect that

You can make use of [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2) to copy the values at the point in time from the `originalArray`

```
...

var tempVal = originalArray[smallest];
originalArray[smallest] = originalArray[i];
originalArray[i] = tempVal;

// Create some new memory
iterations[i] = new int[originalArray.Length];
// Copy the contents 
Array.Copy(originalArray, iterations[i], originalArray.Length);
```

***Note*** this is totally untested and i have no idea if the rest of your code is working as intended

---

**Additional Resources**

[Array.Copy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Copies a range of elements in one Array to another Array and performs
>   type casting and boxing as required.

[Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

> **Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array**. Since this type implements IEnumerable and IEnumerable,
>   you can use foreach iteration on all arrays in C#.

Comment: Yes! This was the fix. Thank you so much, I appreciate it.